# Div's populated using WP_Query behaving weird on mobile browsers, Graphical glitches

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is an overview of the issue on a Wordpress site I am developing.

I have div's populating from a WP_Query. It includes a background image, and some text. When viewing these div's on a mobile browser often this below graphical glitch appears. (more prevalent on Chrome but does appear on safari).

It almost as if they become out of order or try to move but don't load properly.

Additional note, the posts the query is calling are built using Advanced Custom Fields (not sure if that has any relevance).
[Image of glitch seen on chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaf62.png)

Here is the code loading the div's

```
    <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'group',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            array (
                                'taxonomy' => 'class-type',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'speciality',
                            )
                        ),

                );
                $posts = new WP_Query($args);
                if($posts->have_posts()) : 
                    while($posts->have_posts()) : 
                        $posts->the_post();

                        echo '<div class="pt-block chrome-height" onclick="ptmore(this)"  style="background: url(\'',
                        the_field('banner_image'),
                        '\') no-repeat center;">    <div class="pt-name white bold" ><h1 class="bold">',
                        the_title(),
                        '</h1><a class="white bold block-button" ><h3 class="bold">Find out more </h3><img class="arrow-margin" src="/wp-content/themes/bunker/img/parts/arrow-right-yellow.png" width="12" height="12"></a></div>
                            <div id="pt-info-overlay" class="pt-info-overlay" ><div class="pt-info center">
                                                        <h3 class=""></h3><br>
                                                        <h2 class="bold yellow">',
                                                                        the_title(''),
                                                                        '</h2><br><br>
                            <h5 class="">"',the_field('class-info-short'),'"</h5>
                                                                        <a href=',the_permalink(),' class=" bold black-button">Find out more</a>
                                                                        <h3 class="yellow block bold" >Get out of the way</h3>
                                                                        <img src="/wp-content/themes/bunker/img/icons/circle-x.png" width="40" height="40" >


                                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>  

                    </div><div class="clear"></div>';



            ?>

            <?php
                endwhile;
                else: 
                endif;
                wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

This code is used 3 times on the same page to query different terms but are otherwise identical. Here is a link to the development environment to check out the bug. [Development site.](http://thebunker-b.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/group-training/)
Keep in mind the bug can sometime take some time to appear if at all.

Any advice on how to tackle this one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fix your broken HTML. Your system manages to output four `link` elements referring stylesheets even before `<!doctype html>`, which is obviously BS.

Comment: Thanks for picking up on this CBroe. Stupid mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your website is not loading resources properly. Example: CSS files / JavaScript etc. I just tested your site and upon force refresh it loads fine but does not sometime as you said.

There not 100% solution but what I have encountered is beyond my understanding. You site loads some of the CSS files  like "font awesome" "slick" etc before the HTML tag. I think this the problem that interrupt your layout.

You should load your assets / resources using enqueue method in WordPress. Hard coded scripts / stylesheets are not recommended in WordPress.

A proper HTML document must start and ends with html but your site has some link tag out of the `<html>` and that might create render problems (maybe). Fix it.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, Just one of those things I totally overlooked.